# Artemis running on WSL2 not accessible from Windows

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, activemq-artemis

This is a specific question. I am running an Artemis MQ service on WSL2. I would like to access the service from an app running on the Windows side, but I got the following exception:

```
Caused by: ActiveMQNotConnectedException[errorType=NOT_CONNECTED message=AMQ219007: Cannot connect to server(s). Tried with all available servers.]
```

When I run both Artemis and the app on the same "side" (both on WSL or both on Windows, but not at the same time), they work correctly.

Before I installed artemis on WSL, the app running on Linux was able to access the MQ on Windows, so my guess is the problem connected to Artemis being installed on both platform. (However, I checked and no service is running automatically.) Because artemis is not "installed", but unzipped and a broker is created, uninstalling is not possible.

Any idea where the two install is interfering each other?

Note: The web console is also unavailable:

[image]

**UPDATE 1**

Some more information:

I tried to find out any port issue (changed the ports, for example), and to find any reference about port forwarding, but the only info I've found (on the official WSL FAQ), that the ports are shared and we can't talk about forwarding, because they are technically the same (that's why the two instances are conflicting when starting at the same time).

Also, the fact, that earlier (when there were only the Win version installed) I was able to access the Windows version from WSL, indicates some strange behavior other than a port forwarding issue. (And my collegues use this setup (Win -> WSL) at the moment without problem.)

I've even uninstalled (deleted, because Artemis is simply unzipped, not installed) the Windows version, but it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: This seems more like some kind of environmental issue. Perhaps the network forwarding isn't working properly from Windows to the WSL VM where the broker is running. If there was some kind of conflict between the two "installations" of the broker then the broker would fail to start due to the bind address & port already being in use.

Comment: @JustinBertram Yes, surely it is some environmental problem. Also, I can see there is a conflict: I can't start both installation at the same time (as it is expected). But they run alright when starting only one.

Comment: Have you tried binding the broker to an actual IP address or hostname rather than `localhost`?

Comment: @JustinBertram I don't know why, but it helped. See my solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well, running some extra circles, I've found a solution for the problem, thanks to the suggestion of Justin Bertram.

Once a day, when connection (starting a bash) to WSL, it prints some statistics:

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.19.104-microsoft-standard x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage

  System information as of Thu Jul 16 08:58:33 CEST 2020

  System load:  0.0                Processes:             8
  Usage of /:   3.6% of 250.98GB   Users logged in:       0
  Memory usage: 0%                 IPv4 address for eth0: 172.20.246.243
  Swap usage:   0%
```

Here I noticed a local IP address, which was different from the Windows IP address. When I changed my connection from `localhost` to this address, I was able to access the MQ.

This solved my initial problem. On the other hand, some questions still hold: What is this address? Why it is defined on this machine and not on my other? How could I get rid of this redirection of eth0?

UPDATE 1:
I've found some of the answers (although it brings up other questions). At the PC the connection worked by localhost, my Ubuntu uses the shares the IP of eth0 and Windows:

```
>ip addr
6: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 group default qlen 1
    link/ether 10:7b:44:1b:1c:d8
    inet 192.168.1.128/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic
       valid_lft 86394sec preferred_lft 86394sec
```

*(The address 192.168.1.128 is a static DHCP assigned address to the host Windows.)*

On the other computer, where localhost doesn't work, the eth0 interface gets a different IP address.

The (new) question: why and how to make Ubuntu to share IP?

Comment: For what it's worth, asking a new question in an answer is not really how Stack Overflow works. If you have another question just create a new question.

Comment: That was some poetic question I was not intend to dive into. (However, I read a few articles about how WSL2 changed the network routing and how much headache it cause when one would like to access services on WSL2 from "outside".)